# How to set OnClickListener from Activity for Fragment's switch?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have an Activity which has a Fragment. This Fragment has different switches and buttons. Now I can access these Fragment's elements from the Activity.

Now, I want to set an OnClickListener on the Fragment's switch but in the Activity itself. Problem is, from the Activity second time onward switch is not listening.

Comment: Follows the steps outlined [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html): you'll want your fragment to propagate switch changes onto its listener (which will be your activity).

Answer (score 0):

For switch I recommend `OnCheckedChangeListener` instead of `OnClickListener` for listenning events

```
 mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                 // do something when check is selected
            } else {
                 //do something when unchecked
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks. actually I'm using setOnCheckedChangeListener listener only, but it not listens to switch in my activity. :(

Comment: Does your button listen onClickEvent in Activity

Comment: Only first time it listens, but after that it doesn't.

Comment: as now, i have no idea with your problem, please post some code that you have tried so far. then we can easy for help

Answer (score 0):

You can have your onClickListener in a method in you Activity class like below:

```
public OnClickListener switchClickListener()
{
    return new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //code here
        }
    };
}
```

And you can call this method from your fragment and set the Switch OnClicklistener with the code below:

```
switch.setOnClickListener( ((Activity) getActivity).switchClickListener());
```

Comment: Add the code to your question and add the isCheckChanged() method

Answer (score 0):

You can implement OnClickListener at your actvity and on attach you can use that to call onclicklistener. At activity-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {
....
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){

    }
}
}
```

And at fragment-

```
MainActivity mainActivity;
Button button;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mainActivity = (MainActivity) activity;
    button.setOnClickListener(mainActivity);
}
```

Note - The above code works only when your fragment is attached with activity. Recommended way is to use callbacks.